# play-authenticate: Email/Password persist?

Tags: playframework, play-authenticate

Where is Play-authenticate persisting the password in the email/password flow? 
The default models.User class persists the email, name and other fields in the database but does not have a column for password.
I have largely followed the sample code. I am using the User class from the samples - https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate/blob/master/samples/java/play-authenticate-usage/app/models/User.java

Is is being stored in cache? 
If so, where should I inject my code to persist email/password in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is stored in [`LinkedAccount`](https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate/blob/master/samples/java/play-authenticate-usage/app/models/LinkedAccount.java) model with `providerKey` set to `password`. For other providers uses their names as the key i.e. `facebook`, `twitter` etc.